# finding way to Oracle Query SUBSTR and INSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

```
Table Name: DUMMY
Table Data : BGX~UGREP~NSP
Database: Oracle
Column Name: Skills
Expected Output: UGREP
```

I want to fetch data between Symbol (`~`). I was writing below query. but It is not giving expected output

**Query:**

```
select rtrim((SUBSTR(Skill ,INSTR(Skill ,'~')+1)),'~NSP') from DUMMY;
```

Actual Output: `UGRE` (`P` is missing from `UGREP`)

Can someone suggest whats wrong with query or suggest correct query to fetch .

Please note: Input can be different every time but symbol will be there always . and i want data between symbol. So suggest generic query .

Answer (score 1):

Substring

- from the first appearance of `~`
- in length of position of the second appearance MINUS position of the first appearance

In other words:

```
SQL> with dummy (skills) as
  2    (select 'BGX~UGREP~NSP' from dual)
  3  select substr(skills,
  4                instr(skills, '~', 1, 1) + 1,
  5                instr(skills, '~', 1, 2) - instr(skills, '~', 1, 1) - 1
  6               ) result
  7  from dummy;

RESULT
----------
UGREP

SQL>
```